# Vue's v-for with .sync

Tags: vue.js

I have a table row, each containing a select. I wish that when the select option is changed, the data of the parent (containing the table) is updated.

```
<tbody>

      <tr is="itemComponent"
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        v-bind:index="index"
        v-bind:item="item"
        v-bind:item-attribute.sync="item.attribute"
      </tr>

</tbody>
```

Then in itemComponent (receives item-attribute as props):

```
<td>
  <select
    v-bind:value="item-attribute"
    v-on:change="$emit('update:item-attribute', $event.target.value)
  >
    <option v-bind:value="true">Yes</option>
    <option v-bind:value="false">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Using Vue's Chrome extension, I can see that the `<select>` is reactive to `item.attribute` (if I change it manually, the selected option in the select changes), and that it also fires the 'update:item-attribute' event when changed, but it does NOT update the parent's `item.item-attribute` value.

Since .sync is just sugar for `v-on:update:item-attribute`, I would need to write something like this on the parent component if I didn't want to use .sync:

```
<tbody>

      <tr is="itemComponent"
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        v-bind:index="index"
        v-bind:item="item"
        v-bind:item-attribute="item.attribute"
        v-on:update:item-attribute="updateItemAttribute"
      </tr>

</tbody>

methods: {

  updateItemAttribute: function(index,attributeValue) {

    this.items[index].attribute = attributeValue;

  }

}
```

And, on the child component, change the emit call in the select to (considering index is :

`v-on:change="$emit('update:item-attribute', index, $event.target.value)`

Shouldn't .sync help me on this and avoid having to write all this code? I couldn't find any mention of it working with v-for.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/g5bv0esd/1/ . I have also submitted a new Vue issue in https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8373

Comment: The answer is that the event name should be camelCase. Not kebab-case. `$emit('update:itemAttribute',...)`. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the event name should be camelCase, not kebab-case, at least for now.

The "at least for now" is because this is definitely confusing since Vue's documentation explicitly says to "always use `kebab-case` as event names" (see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)), but unfortunately you must use `camelCase` when using the `update:eventName` with the `.sync` modifier.

Vue's developers are aware of this inconsistency and **there's an open issue to either change the code behavior or rewrite the docs in this point**. It also doesn't help that, as of now, the examples in the `.sync` modifier use event names with single words. See https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/1648 for updates.

So, for now, when using .sync modifier, you **should use** `$emit('update:propNameInCamelCase`)`.

Do **not** use `$emit('update:prop-name-in-kebab-case`)` otherwise it won't work.

Thanks to @Jacob Goh for opening the github issue.